# vb if statement: how many and's can you have

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

I have an if statement like this:

```
If r1.Left < r2.Right AndAlso r2.Right < r1.Right AndAlso r2.Top + r2.Height > r1.Top Then
```

I am wondering if it is bad to have so many `AndAlso`'s. It does work it's just confusing to figure out whats happening. Is there a way of doing this test in a simpler way? or is this the correct way of doing things?

Comment: You know about the [`Rectangle.Contains` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0kh3ee9e.aspx), right? But more generally, if the library doesn't provide a method to accomplish the test you desire, you could write your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, MSDN documentation doesn't say anything about the maximum number of conditions that can be used in an `If` statement – so any limit is probably governed by available stack space and it's highly improbable you would ever get anywhere near that.

As for the practice: it's not bad in coding terms but it can, as you say, become difficult to read. I personally tend to just use line continuations to make such statements more readable:

```
If r1.Left < r2.Right _
    AndAlso r2.Right < r1.Right _
    AndAlso r2.Top + r2.Height > r1.Top Then
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always introduce a new variable or method to improve readability.

So instead of

```
If r1.Left < r2.Right AndAlso r2.Right < r1.Right AndAlso r2.Top + r2.Height > r1.Top Then
```

something like

```
Function RectIsInsideOf(r1 As ..., r2 As ...) As Bool
    Return r1.Left < r2.Right AndAlso 
           r2.Right < r1.Right AndAlso 
           r2.Top + r2.Height > r1.Top 
End Function

...

If RectIsInsideOf(r1, r2) Then ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you don't have any limitations on how many operators you can use in an if statement. Furthermore it is quite all right (by programmers point of view) to use as many as you want, after all, this is what if statement is about. However if you are facing situations that require checking too many operators then you must consider a different approach.

In your specific example the code you are using contains only two AndAlso operators which is not big overhead for your program. If you are going to check for this condition only in one location in your program then your approach can be considered as the right one, if you are going to need this checking in many locations then it is wise to write a function for that as BigYellowCactus suggests.

Hope this helps...